# how to check data table row has empty space

Tags: c#, datatable

how to check datatable row **has empty space?**

i know how to check datatable row has null or not now i want to know **empty row**

```
       foreach (DataRow _dr in obj_dt.Rows)
        {
            if (obj_dt.Rows[0]["Measurement"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                combo_mesurmnt.Items.Add(obj_dt.Rows[0]["Measurement"].ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Rony Lol... tight slapp

Comment: if your not welling to answer means don't response to me ..anyway thanks..

Comment: @Jana- we are here to help you... but the way you wrote the question that cause me to write this comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have a mistake in your code:

- You access `obj_dt.Rows[0]`, although you probably mean `_dr`.

Then, there are a few things that could be improved:

- You can use `DataRow.Field<string>`, which is more elegant than `ToString` if you know that the underlying DB field is of type `string`.

Now, to answer your question: It depends on what you mean by "empty space".

- If you mean "empty", you can just check with [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

  ```
  foreach (DataRow _dr in obj_dt.Rows)
  {
      string measurement = _dr.Field<String>("Measurement");
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(measurement))
          combo_mesurmnt.Items.Add(measurement);
  }
  ```
- If *strings consisting only of spaces* should be filtered as well, the following will work:

  ```
  foreach (DataRow _dr in obj_dt.Rows)
  {
      string measurement = _dr.Field<String>("Measurement");
      if (measurement != null && measurement.Trim() != "")
          combo_mesurmnt.Items.Add(measurement);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
   foreach (DataRow _dr in obj_dt.Rows)
    {
        if (obj_dt.Rows[0]["Measurement"].tostring() != "")
        {
            combo_mesurmnt.Items.Add(obj_dt.Rows[0]["Measurement"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

try this...,

Answer (score 1):

use `IsNullOrEmpty`

```
var rowContent = combo_mesurmnt.Items.Add(obj_dr.Rows[0]["Measurement"].ToString());
if (!IsNullOrEmpty(rowContent))
{
   combo_mesurmnt.Items.Add(rowContent);
}
```